# Using .resjson files instead of .resx files outside Windows 8 apps

Tags: .net, windows-8

Windows 8 HTML applications allow resource files in JSON format.

[image]

Is it possible to use them on other applications or class libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.resjson` file itself is just simple JSON, so sure you can use it elsewhere.  The interpretation of the contents is what's unique to the `WinJS.Resources` functionality, you can take a look at how some it works by opening up `ui.js` within the References section of your project and finding where the `WinJS.Resources` namespace is defined.

[How to load String Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465248%28v=win.10%29.aspx) may help as well, though it's covering the different ways to pull resources into your WinJS app, and it appears you're looking to leverage the "Resources engine" in apps that aren't WinJS?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it would be much simpler than xml files. If there is a way, it would be great.